# No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=, VALID_ARCHS=armv7k) Xcode 7 beta 3

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7-beta3

My app have a watch kit support.

Previously, with **Xcode 6.4** my app was running properly.

After updating with **Xcode 7 beta 3** I am getting this error -

No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=, VALID_ARCHS=armv7k).

I am not sure in which target to make changes for this dependency.

Currently,

my **watch kit extension** architecture configuration is

[image]

and my **watch kit app** architecture configuration is

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

I encounter the same problem on more recent **Xcode Beta** as well.

I able to compile now by adding `i386` to Valid Architectures alongside `armv7k`. Probably because of 32 bit legacy library in my project. It also works just by itself (only using `i386`). Weird.

Not sure if there's any other further implications though.

[image: i386 on build settings]

Comment: I still have this problem even my Xcode is 7.1. Adding i386 to Valid Architectures fixed problem. Does anybody have a clue why Apple didn't fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter this problem when adding a watch os target to the existing the project,

Then I changed the **Valid Architectures to armv7k**, and then removed all the exiting architetures in watchkit app target and also in the watchkit extension target